# Navigation through breadcrumbs in angularjs

Tags: angularjs-directive

I am using angularJs for the front end development.I have a requirement where I need to navigate to the previous page from my current page (using bread crumbs). Currently I tried using ng-switch to go back to the previous page .Is there any better approach or predefined feature that supports the same ?if so please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the angular-app which contains a breadcrumbs service:

https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/app/header.tpl.html

https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/services/breadcrumbs.js

It also uses ng-switch and ng-repeat. You can get the breadcrumb items via "breadcrumbs.getAll()" and the service is updated when a route is changed.